# batch edit photos to same reference photo

Tags: viewfinder, remote

I apologize in advance if I over explain this but I'm not sure of the proper terms to use to phrase my question.
Ok so, I do stop motion videos and whatnot. I use a samsung digital camera that has remote viewfinder,  which allows me to use my phone as a remote shutter button and viewfinder. Options are very  limited in this mode.  You can turn on and off the flash, set the timer and change the size of the photo and that's it.  My problem is with a set of photos I took for stop motion sequence.  For some reason, about 7 or 8 photos in this sequence look completely different than the others taken at the same time. [image: What it should look like]

[image: what they are]

Is there any way to adjust the second photo to look like the first? It doesn't have to be exact, just close enough to blend with the rest.  It would be better to do them all at the same time to cut down on the variations between  images

This is something that has never happened to me before. and I'm not sure what caused it, if it was an autofocus thing or what.  I know I didn't change anything during the shoot yet I still ended up with these rouge photos.  I hope to find a solution to my problem otherwise I would have to redo the whole sequence which was very time consuming...

I appreciate any opinions or suggestions any of you are willing to give, and value any and all help and advice, thanks much

Bostain

Answer (score 2):

If you shot this project in jpg you are only going to be able to get close. The main change between the shots is the white balance. So if you can turn off auto white balance and chose the best one for your project you can prevent this issue in the future. I made some changes using adobe Lightroom to the white balance, exposure (-.3), lowered the black point and did some other color tweaks in the HSL panel and the split toning panel. Without spending a bunch of time on it this is the best I could do.[image]